# How to first order by column A, return a top-3, then order the result by column B in one query?

Tags: mysql

(Please refer to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9ff0/4) for a working example of this post)

I have a table with stock information, as follows:

```
sp100_id  _date         bullishness  agreement
----------------------------------------------
1         2011-03-16    1.01          0.33
1         2011-03-17    0.85          1.28
1         2011-03-18    0.89          1.25
1         2011-03-21    1.46          1.21
1         2011-03-22    0.39          2.53
2         2011-03-16    3.07          1.27
2         2011-03-17    2.09          0.80
2         2011-03-18    0.91          0.12
2         2011-03-21    1.50          0.00
2         2011-03-22    2.62          1.10
3         2011-03-16    0.73          1.13
3         2011-03-17    1.13          1.21
3         2011-03-18    1.12          0.45
3         2011-03-21    1.00          1.01
3         2011-03-22    1.00          0.53
4         2011-03-16    0.40          1.10
4         2011-03-17    2.40          0.03
4         2011-03-18    3.16          0.10
4         2011-03-21    0.86          0.50
4         2011-03-22    1.00          0.10
```

I need to order the companies (`sp100_id`) by their averge `bullishness` over time into a top-3:

```
SELECT 
  sp100_id, 
  AVG(bullishness) as bullishness, 
  AVG(agreement) AS agreement 
FROM stocks 
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2011-03-16' AND '2011-03-22' 
GROUP BY sp100_id LIMIT 3
```

This works fine, as the result is

```
SP100_ID    BULLISHNESS AGREEMENT
2           2.038           0.658
4           1.564           0.366
3           0.996           0.866
```

Now that I have the top-3, I need the top-3 to be re-ordered by `AGREEMENT`, ascending:

```
SP100_ID    BULLISHNESS AGREEMENT
4           1.564           0.366
2           2.038           0.658
3           0.996           0.866
```

Is this possible to do with one query? I tried the following but it didn't work. It still only orders by `bullishness`

```
SELECT 
  sp100_id, 
  AVG(bullishness) as bullishness, 
  AVG(agreement) AS agreement 
FROM stocks 
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2011-03-16' AND '2011-03-22' 
GROUP BY sp100_id 
ORDER BY bullishness DESC, agreement ASC LIMIT 3
```

So to be clear: (1) I need to find the top-3 companies with highest average bullsihness (2) this top-3 then needs to be ordered from lowest to highest agreement. Preferably with one query. Do you know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *structured* query language because you can build structures in which queries (aka virtual tables) are nested inside other queries.

Take your first query, which is correct except it needs its own ORDER BY clause, and nest it in another, like so.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
           SELECT sp100_id,  
                  AVG(bullishness) as bullishness, 
                  AVG(agreement) AS agreement 
             FROM stocks 
            WHERE _date BETWEEN '2011-03-16' AND '2011-03-22' 
         GROUP BY sp100_id
         ORDER BY bullishness DESC
            LIMIT 3
  ) subquery
  ORDER BY agreement ASC
```

Go fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9ff0/7/0